# JQuery Datatables + Codeigniter (Static cols)

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, codeigniter, datatables

I am using Codeigniter with JQuery Datatables to present data from MYSQL database with realtime updates via AJAX/JSON requests. I am not the original developer of this code that's why I am not being able to solve this problem I guess.

What I have is a table with 26 columns, not all of them are yet populated but it seems that all of them are there straight from the database. This is how piece of the code from json_table function looks:

```
$this->load->model('aircraft_model');
$this->load->model('nats_model');

$aColumns = array('FlightSts', 'TblOrder', 'Callsign', 'Destination', 'NAT', 'SELCAL', 'CldFL', 'CldMach', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'FlightID');
$sTable = 'naecs_aircraft';
```

$stable seems to be mysql table which is correct,
$acolumns seems to be all fields from the mysql table naecs_aircraft. That's all correct and it even works but in Second last column, just before FlightID I want to populate a button. So basically In the second last collumn I want to have a button.

How to do it?

Regards,
Maciej.

@edit1

This is whole function within the controller ajax.php:

```
public function json_table(){
    $this->access->requires(ACCESS_USER);
    $this->load->model('aircraft_model');
    $this->load->model('nats_model');

    $aColumns = array('FlightSts', 'TblOrder', 'Callsign', 'Destination', 'NAT', 'SELCAL', 'CldFL', 'CldMach', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'FlightID');
    $sTable = 'naecs_aircraft';

    $iDisplayStart = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayStart', true);
    $iDisplayLength = $this->input->get_post('iDisplayLength', true);
    $iSortCol_0 = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_0', true);
    $iSortingCols = $this->input->get_post('iSortingCols', true);
    $sSearch = $this->input->get_post('sSearch', true);
    $sEcho = $this->input->get_post('sEcho', true);

    if(isset($iSortCol_0))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<intval($iSortingCols); $i++)
        {
            $iSortCol = $this->input->get_post('iSortCol_'.$i, true);
            $bSortable = $this->input->get_post('bSortable_'.intval($iSortCol), true);
            $sSortDir = $this->input->get_post('sSortDir_'.$i, true);

            if($bSortable == 'true')
            {
                if ($aColumns[$iSortCol] != ' '){
                    $this->aircraft_model->json_table_sort($aColumns, $iSortCol, $sSortDir);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(isset($sSearch) && !empty($sSearch))
    {
        for($i=0; $i<count($aColumns); $i++)
        {
            if ($aColumns[$i] != ' '){
                $bSearchable = $this->input->get_post('bSearchable_'.$i, true);
                if(isset($bSearchable) && $bSearchable == 'true')
                {
                    $this->aircraft_model->json_table_filter($aColumns, $i, $sSearch);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $rResult = $this->aircraft_model->json_table_select($aColumns, $sTable);
    $iFilteredTotal = $this->aircraft_model->json_table_found($aColumns);
    $iTotal = $this->aircraft_model->count_all($sTable);

    $output = array(
        'sEcho' => intval($sEcho),
        'iTotalRecords' => $iTotal,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $iFilteredTotal,
        'aaData' => array()
    );

    $headers = array('3active' => FALSE, '2cleared' => FALSE, '4closed' => FALSE, '1entered' => FALSE, '5disconnected' => FALSE);

    foreach($rResult->result_array() as $aRow)
    {
        $row = array();

        foreach($aColumns as $col)
        {
            @$row[] = $aRow[$col];
        }

        $databit = $row;
        $databit['DT_RowId'] = $aRow['FlightID'];
        $databit['DT_RowName'] = $aRow['Callsign'];
        $output['aaData'][] = $databit;
        $headers[$aRow['FlightSts']] = TRUE;
    }

    foreach ($headers as $key => $value){
        if ($value == FALSE){
            $output['aaData'][] = array($key, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
        }
    }

    $output['aaData'][] = array('No More Aircraft', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

tableinit.js:

```
function initTable(){
    oTable = $('#main-table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "sServerMethod": "GET",
        "sAjaxSource": "ajax/json_table",
        "oLanguage": { "sProcessing": "<i class='icon-refresh icon-spin'></i>" },
        "sDom": "<'pull-right'r><'row'<'span8'l>>tS",
        "sScrollY": "400px",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [ 
        { "bVisible": false,  "aTargets": [ 1, 25 ] },
        ],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            $('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr("name", "callsign");
            $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr("name", "destination");
            $('td:eq(2)', nRow).attr("name", "nat");
            $('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr("name", "selcal");
            $('td:eq(4)', nRow).attr("name", "lvl");
            $('td:eq(5)', nRow).attr("name", "mach");
        },
    }).rowGrouping({ iGroupingColumnIndex: 0, sGroupingClass: 'nodrop', bSetGroupingClassOnTR: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched all around and I finally got solution to it, after

```
foreach($aColumns as $col)
{
        @$row[] = $aRow[$col];
}
```

I just added:

```
$row[24] = '<a data-toggle="modal" href=#clrAircraft" data target="#clrAircraft">Clearance</a>';
```

Very simple solution, this will take col 24 out of the aColumns array so col 25 of the table and add anything that you will add in it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find where your data is being built up for the table, and add the html there. You haven't given us enough information to answer completely, but you can populate a datatable in one of two methods:

1) create a table in normal php output, then just initialize

2) use an ajax source to load the data

Both ways are essentially the same for your problem - find where the table row data is being created, and modify it there s that one column has the button html you want

Comment: I tried to find it but it seems like its all generated by javascript of datatables. I added the whole controller of json_table + init code.

Comment: so you see that "sAjaxSource": "ajax/json_table" is there - that means it is the second method I mentioned. In the foreach over your aCols set, you'll want to flag & modify the column somehow before passing it into the row array. A little hard to read, but put some var_dumps and you should see what is happening

Comment: Tried to var_dump but when I try to do that it gives me an error from datatables that its not being able to parse JSON as JSON formatting  is wrong.

Comment: yes, it will do  that :-) your output is messed up, but it is only temporary so you can have a look at your data row & see what is happening. Your other (better, but more time consuming) alternative is to separate out your code so you can properly test it by calling that function from a testing controller